# Mtl files seem to not be loading with obj files

Tags: three.js

I am using some files to display a coffee table and a cashiers desk in a store. I have been using three.js for some stuff for a while, but I haven't had to load outside files before. For some reason, the obj files load and display but they are only grey. The mtl loads do not produce any errors, they just don't seem to have any effect.

The item is in code pen where you can see the full js and html code.

https://codepen.io/jfoxworth/pen/OJRzZKG

to move the person in the pen, use w, s, a, and d

```
    var scene, camera, cameras, cameraIndex, renderer, controls, clock, player, xStart, zStart;

init();








function init(){

  xStart = 0;
  zStart = 0;

  clock = new THREE.Clock();
  
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  let col = 0x605050;
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color( col );
  scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( col, 10, 100 );
  
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
  camera.position.set(0, 4, 7);
  camera.lookAt(0,1.5,0);
  
  const ambient = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffbb, 0x080820);
  scene.add(ambient);
  
  const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, 1);
  light.position.set( 1, 10, 6);
  scene.add(light);
  
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  
  var texture = loader.load( 'https://makstudio.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/objfiles/marble1.png', function ( texture ) {
    texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.offset.set( 0, 0 );
    texture.repeat.set( 20, 20 );
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

  const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(200, 200);
  const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({map:texture});
  const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
  plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
  scene.add(plane);
  });
  
  




  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

  var texture = loader.load( 'https://makstudio.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/objfiles/wood1.jpg', function ( texture ) {
      texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
      texture.offset.set( 0, 0 );
      texture.repeat.set( 1, 1 );
  


    // The walls
    const wallmaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({map: texture});

    // Front Left wall
    const wallgeometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(22,10,0.3);
    wall1 = new THREE.Mesh(wallgeometry1, wallmaterial);
    wall1.position.x=-13 + xStart;
    wall1.position.z=-4 + zStart;
    scene.add(wall1);


    // Front right wall
    const wallgeometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(4,10,0.3);
    wall2 = new THREE.Mesh(wallgeometry2, wallmaterial);
    wall2.position.x=4 + xStart;
    wall2.position.z=-4 + zStart;
    scene.add(wall2);


    // main right wall
    const wallgeometry3 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(16,10,0.3);
    wall3 = new THREE.Mesh(wallgeometry3, wallmaterial);
    wall3.position.x=5.75 + xStart;
    wall3.position.z=-12 + zStart;
    wall3.rotateY(Math.PI/2);
    scene.add(wall3);

    // main back wall
    const wallgeometry4 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(30,10,0.3);
    wall4 = new THREE.Mesh(wallgeometry4, wallmaterial);
    wall4.position.x=-9 + xStart;
    wall4.position.z=-20 + zStart;
    scene.add(wall4);

    // main left wall
    const wallgeometry5 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(16,10,0.3);
    wall5 = new THREE.Mesh(wallgeometry5, wallmaterial);
    wall5.position.x=-24 + xStart;
    wall5.position.z=-12 + zStart;
    wall5.rotateY(Math.PI/2);
    scene.add(wall5);





      // dr wall 1
      const wallgeometry6 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5,10,0.3);
      wall6 = new THREE.Mesh(wallgeometry6, wallmaterial);
      wall6.position.x=-10 + xStart;
      wall6.position.z=-12 + zStart;
      wall6.rotateY(Math.PI/2);
      scene.add(wall6);
    
      // dr wall 2
      const wallgeometry7 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5,10,0.3);
      wall7 = new THREE.Mesh(wallgeometry7, wallmaterial);
      wall7.position.x=-16 + xStart;
      wall7.position.z=-12 + zStart;
      wall7.rotateY(Math.PI/2);
      scene.add(wall7);


      // dr wall 3
      const wallgeometry8 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(6.5,10,0.3);
      wall8 = new THREE.Mesh(wallgeometry8, wallmaterial);
      wall8.position.x=-13 + xStart;
      wall8.position.z=-9.5 + zStart;
      scene.add(wall8);


      // dr wall 4
      const wallgeometry9 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(6.5,10,0.3);
      wall9 = new THREE.Mesh(wallgeometry9, wallmaterial);
      wall9.position.x=-13 + xStart;
      wall9.position.z=-14.5 + zStart;
      scene.add(wall9);
  
  } );



/*
  // The large racks of clothes
  var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

  // Rack to the right as you walk in
  loader.load( 'https://makstudio.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/objfiles/clothes1.obj', function ( rack1 ) {
    rack1.position.x=5;
    rack1.position.z=-10;
    scene.add( rack1 );


    // Rack to the left as you walk in
    const rack2 = rack1.clone();
    rack2.position.x=-7;
    rack2.position.z=-5;
    rack2.rotateY(Math.PI/2);
    scene.add( rack2 );


  } );
*/








  var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

  

  var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
  mtlLoader.load( 'https://makstudio.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/objfiles/coffee_table.mtl', function( materials ) {
  
    materials.preload();
  
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    objLoader.load( 'https://makstudio.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/objfiles/coffee_table.obj', function ( object ) {
  
      mesh = object;
      mesh.scale.set(0.1,0.1,0.1);
      mesh.position.x=1 + xStart;
      mesh.position.z=0 + zStart;
      scene.add( mesh );
  
    } );
  
  } );
  

  // Coffee Tables
  loader.load( 'https://makstudio.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/objfiles/coffee_table.obj', function ( ct1 ) {
    ct1.scale.set(0.1,0.1,0.1);
    ct1.position.x=-4 + xStart;
    ct1.position.z=-10 + zStart;
    scene.add( ct1 );

    const ct2 = ct1.clone();
    ct2.position.x=-4 + xStart;
    ct2.position.z=-14 + zStart;
    scene.add( ct2 );

  } );


  // The cashiers table
  loader.load( 'https://makstudio.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/objfiles/cashier.obj', function ( cash ) {
    cash.scale.set(0.035,0.035,0.035);
    cash.position.x=-18 + xStart;
    cash.position.z=-7 + zStart;
    scene.add( cash );

  } );

    




  /*
  var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
  mtlLoader.load( 'https://makstudio.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/objfiles/coffee_table.mtl', function( ct1 ) {
  
    ct1.preload();
  
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials( ct1 );
    loader.load( 'https://makstudio.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/objfiles/coffee_table.obj', function ( ct1 ) {
      ct1.scale.set(0.1,0.1,0.1);
      ct1.position.x=-15;
      ct1.position.y=0;
      scene.add( ct1 );
  
    } );
  
  } );

  */



  const grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 200, 80);
  scene.add( grid );
  
  //Add meshes here
  player = new THREE.Group();
  scene.add(player);
  
  const bodyGeometry = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry(0.5, 0.3, 1.6, 20);
  const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0xffff00 });
  const body = new THREE.Mesh(bodyGeometry, material);
  body.position.y = 0.8;
  body.scale.z = 0.5;
  player.add(body);
  const headGeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(0.3, 20, 15);
  const head = new THREE.Mesh(headGeometry, material);
  head.position.y = 2.0;
  player.add(head);
  
  cameras = [];
  cameraIndex = 0; 
  
  const followCam = new THREE.Object3D();
  followCam.position.copy(camera.position);
  player.add(followCam);
  cameras.push(followCam);
  
  const frontCam = new THREE.Object3D();
  frontCam.position.set(0, 3, -8);
  player.add(frontCam);
  cameras.push(frontCam);
  
  const overheadCam = new THREE.Object3D();
  overheadCam.position.set(-10, 20, -10);
  cameras.push(overheadCam);
  
  addKeyboardControl();
  
  const btn = document.getElementById('camera-btn');
  btn.addEventListener('click', changeCamera);
  
  window.addEventListener( 'resize', resize, false);
  
  update();
}

function changeCamera(){
  cameraIndex++;
  if (cameraIndex>=cameras.length) cameraIndex = 0;
}

function addKeyboardControl(){
    document.addEventListener( 'keydown', keyDown );
    document.addEventListener( 'keyup', keyUp );
}
  
function keyDown(evt){
    let forward = (player.userData!==undefined && player.userData.move!==undefined) ? player.userData.move.forward : 0;
    let turn = (player.userData!=undefined && player.userData.move!==undefined) ?  player.userData.move.turn : 0;
    
    switch(evt.keyCode){
      case 87://W
        forward = -1;
        break;
      case 83://S
        forward = 1;
        break;
      case 65://A
        turn = 1;
        break;
      case 68://D
        turn = -1;
        break;
    }
    
    playerControl(forward, turn);
}
  
function keyUp(evt){
    let forward = (player.userData!==undefined && player.userData.move!==undefined) ? player.userData.move.forward : 0;
    let turn = (player.move!=undefined && player.userData.move!==undefined) ?  player.userData.move.turn : 0;
    
    switch(evt.keyCode){
      case 87://W
        forward = 0;
        break;
      case 83://S
        forward = 0;
        break;
      case 65://A
        turn = 0;
        break;
      case 68://D
        turn = 0;
        break;
    }
    
    playerControl(forward, turn);
}

function playerControl(forward, turn){
    if (forward==0 && turn==0){
      delete player.userData.move;
    }else{
      if (player.userData===undefined) player.userData = {};
      this.player.userData.move = { forward, turn }; 
    }
}

function update(){
  requestAnimationFrame( update );
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  
  const dt = clock.getDelta();
  
  if (player.userData!==undefined && player.userData.move!==undefined){
    player.translateZ(player.userData.move.forward * dt * 5);
    player.rotateY(player.userData.move.turn * dt);
  }
  
  camera.position.lerp(cameras[cameraIndex].getWorldPosition(new THREE.Vector3()), 0.05);
  const pos = player.position.clone();
  pos.y += 3;
  camera.lookAt(pos);

  cameras[2].position.x = pos.x;
  cameras[2].position.z = pos.z;

}

function resize(){
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}
```

Comment: It seems the MTL is loaded correctly and the material which is referred by the OBJ file is applied. However, the material has a light-gray color so you probably see not much of a difference compared to the default material.

Comment: The models have coloring that is dark wood on top and metal for the legs. There is no material that is applied to the objects in the code pen

Comment: OK. It does look like the files are applied. There must be some error in how I downloaded them?